# Plone 4 : Turn Search Results into RSS feed

Tags: search, rss, plone

How does one turn search results in a Plone 4 website into an RSS feed?

I've looked at this link : [Syndicate News Items](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/syndicate-news-items) but it seems outdated.

Answer (score 4):

There a link in the Search page for just that ( "*Subscribe to an always-updated feed of these search terms*" ). For example:

http://plone.org/search?SearchableText=collective

the corresponding link is:

http://plone.org/search_rss?SearchableText=collective

Comment: Thank you for the response.I have an advanced search that displays results, but there is no link to display in RSS as you mentioned above. Note that I've already activated RSS syndication. Is there a way one can make it manually appear? Currently I'm manipulating the _current_page_url_ to enable RSS.